# How to generate a textbox on top of a mapbox map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am rather new to JavaScript, but I have this mapbox map that I hope to add a dynamic `textbox` on top of. Right now, I have a `window.setinterval`command running that adds new markers to the map every half second or so. What I want to do is add a changing `textbox` that displays a date, which changes with every window time interval.

Could anyone help me with adding this `textbox` in the corner or something so that it displays a changing date (starting from 1/1/16 on) on top of the mapbox box?

Comment: Oh man. This is going to have people yelling and screaming at you. "What have you tried?" "What do you have so far?" Meh, Ill bite. In the future, these are things you want to include in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-with-timer"></div>
  <div class="element-with-map"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }

  .element-with-timer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
  }
</style>
```

Within the `.element-with-timer` css styles, would would then place the element where you want on the page by changing "left" or "top" values.

If you want to keep the timer in the same position, regardless of scroll position, change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`